# Rails3 route STI Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sti

I have `Vehicle` and STI models `Car` and `Motorcycle`.

I have currently routes configured as below:

```
resources :vehicles
resources :cars
resources :motorcycles
```

However, I'm thinking it would look prettier like this:

```
/vehicles/ #all the methods of vehicles_controller
/vehicles/cars/ #all the methods of cars_controller
/vehicles/motorcycles/ #all the methods of motorcycles_controller
```

How should I go about configuring it to get that URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do following:

```
resources :vehicles
scope "/vehicles" do
  resources :cars, :motorcycles
end
```

Or this way:

```
resources :vehicles
resources :cars, :path => "/vehicles/cars"
resources :motorcycles, :path => "/vehicles/motorcycles"
```

You can find more information about rails routing here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

You can write :

```
resources :vehicles do
  resources :cars
  resources :motorcycles
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write nested routes like this:

```
resources :vehicles do
  resources :cars
  resources :motorcycles
end
```

This will give you routes like:

```
/vehicles #index action for vehicles controller
/vehicles/:id #show action for vehicles controller
/vehicles/:vehicle_id/cars #index action for cars controller, with the :vehicle_id param available
/vehicles/:vehicle_id/cars/:id #show action for cars controller, with the :vehicle_id param available
etc.
```